# 2 slideshows at once office powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have 2 slides I want to show them simultaneously and at the same time on monitor,is there any way to do it? it seems that I should go to Slideshow Tab and then slideshow setup but I don't know what else to do.In view it has arrange all but I want to when presenting them show them at the same time
Also I find [this link](http://officeone.mvps.org/powershow/powershow_sync_shows.html) but I don't know how to do and where the Synchronous Shows are?my office is 2010

Comment: how many monitors you have?

Comment: one Monitor. I got it I need to install powershow of officeone it is another office software different from powerpoint

Comment: http://officeone.mvps.org/powershow/powershow_install.html

Answer (score 0):

*Two methods, to accomplish two different things.*

### 1) Two simultaneous slideshows, both in full screen

It is possible to have two ppt slideshows running in parallel on a laptop, so you can switch between them without exiting the actual slideshow view.

It is actually quite trivial : open the two presentations, launch slideshow for the first one, with `alt tab` cycle back to the PowerPoint window (the icon of the slideshow is more white with red accents, and the icon of the PPT window is red with white accents; the title of the slideshow window also says "PowerPoint Slideshow"), and then select the second presentation, launch slideshow again. With `alt tab` it is easy to cycle between the two slideshows.

### 2) Two simultaneous slideshows, both showing together in half of the screen

It is also possible to show two slideshows next to each other on the same monitor (although that gives your obviously quite some black space on your window if they are in landscape, but it works quite nicely if they are in portrait). This works in PPT 2013 and later, but not sure about earlier version.

Go to "Slideshow" menu, click on "Set Up Slide Show", under Show Type, select "Browsed by an individual (window)", click "OK". If you now put your presentation in Slide Show view (F5 or click on icon), the Slide Show will be viewed in the actual Power Point window (so contrary to the standard/default Slide Show view, which opens in a new full screen view). So you now can resize the window as you want. If you now do the same for the second presentation, you have two Slide Shows open.  ([source](https://nutsandboltsspeedtraining.com/powerpoint-tutorials/view-two-powerpoint-presentations-at-the-same-time/))

You then can use the neat Windows 10 trick to drag the one window to one side, so it automatically occupies half of the screen, and then you can select the second one to have them both side-by-side, each on exactly half of the screen. Or you can resize the two windows manually.

Comment: @Negin I did see your comment regarding the other software that exists to show various presentation on different monitors, but I thought to give my answer separately, as it might help others that are looking for what is possible with only PowerPoint.